# Google Drive API Cannot create Folder in parent Folder

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-drive-api, service-accounts, google-api-nodejs-client

Hello I am trying to create a folder in a parent folder by doing this:

```
const folderMetaData = {
  name: getDate(),
  mimeType: "application/vnd.google-apps.folder",
  parents: [folderId],
};
const folderCreate = await drive.files.create({
  resource: folderMetaData,
  fields: "id",
});
```

The Service account has "Contributor" Role.

The error I get is

Error: Error: Error: File not found: "ID OF THE PARENT FOLDER"

I am very baffled

Comment: From `The Service account has "Contributor" Role.`, I guessed that `drive` of your client might be the service account. From your error message of `File not found`, I'm worried that the service account might have no permission to access the folder. Because for example, when you want to retrieve the folder in your Drive using the service account, this cannot be achieved by default. So, I would like to ask 2 questions. 1. Where is the folder of your `folderId`? 2. Does the service account have permission to access the folder? First, I would like to understand your current situation correctly.

Comment: The folder is shared with the service account and the service account is given contributor role access to that shared folder

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now, I noticed that an answer has already been posted. In this case, I would like to respect the existing answer and discussion. I believe your issue will be resolved.

Answer (score 1):

The service account is not you, it must be granted access to the folderid.

go to the google drive web app take the service account email address and share the folder with it like you would any other user.  Then the service account will have access to folderId

Or if this is a google workspace domain account, you can configure domain wide delegation with the service account and delegate to the user who owns the folder.

Service account cloud contributor role has nothing to do with google drive.

Comment: It couldn't find it because it was a shared drive with the service account and i had to pass in supportsAllDrives: true for it to find that

Answer (score 0):

Yes because **folderId** is not defined

You need to know how to Create Folder first.

For more Information visit the Google API Guides link and you will find **how to get the Folder Id & Create a file in a folder**

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/folder

It will clear all your doubts.

Comment: I am passing folderId which is the id from 
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/id here

Answer (score 0):

```
    const { data } = await drive.files.create({
  media,
  requestBody: {
    name: fileName,
    parents: [folderCreate]
  },
  supportsAllDrives: true
});
```

supportsAllDrives was needed

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. As the posts above suggests, "supportsAllDrives" query parameter was missing in my code. If anyone is looking for a Python version, feel free to use this one:

```
file_metadata_folder = {
    'name': 'folderName',
    'parents': ['parentFolderID],
    'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder',
    'driveId': 'driveID'
}

reponse = Google_DriveClient.files().create(body=file_metadata_folder, fields='id', supportsAllDrives="true").execute()
```